# Why my ActiveMQ doesn't start

Tags: java, windows, activemq-classic

Ive been searching a lot and i couldn't figure out why, my java is properly installed. And the environment property is correct too.

Trying to install the ActiveMQ in Windows 7 64bit.
This is the ActiveMQ 5.8.0.

So with Administrator Cmd i run the bat inside Win64 "InstallService.bat", installs it.
But when i try to start it using "net start activemq" it throws an error related to the java.command in the wrapper.conf.

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/07/29 13:00:10 | Launching a JVM...
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2013/07/29 13:00:10 | Unable to execute Java command.  The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2013/07/29 13:00:10 |     "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -Dactivemq.home="C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\.." -Dactivemq.base="C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\.." -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\../conf/broker.ks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\../conf/broker.ts" -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Dactivemq.conf="C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\../conf" -Dactivemq.data="C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\../data" -Xmx1024m -Djava.library.path="C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\../bin/win64" -classpath "C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\../bin/wrapper.jar;C:\apache-activemq-5.8.0\bin\win64\..\../bin/activemq.jar" -Dwrapper.key="b0Z3zqiLBNs16vNL" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.pid=8120 -Dwrapper.version="3.2.3" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.service="TRUE" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.apache.activemq.console.Main start
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2013/07/29 13:00:10 | Critical error: wait for JVM process failed
```

Do you know what's wrong? :/

These are the wrapper properties in the wrapper.conf file

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Properties
#********************************************************************

# wrapper.debug=TRUE
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_HOME=%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_BASE=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_CONF=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%/conf
set.default.ACTIVEMQ_DATA=%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%/data
wrapper.working.dir=.

# Java Application
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check your JAVA_HOME and make sure it's actually pointed to the right place. It looks like the bat file is trying to run java.exe, tehn wait for the JVM to start up, but it never finds the java.exe

Comment: Yes, checked the JAVA_HOME and its pointing to this location C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin

Comment: But still not working :/

Comment: Please search in logs file and send them

Comment: I had the same issue, I solved it by adding the location of JDK bin folder into PATH variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I had to uninstall the ActiveMQ.

Updating the wrapper.config file in both the Win32 and Win64

wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe

installing the ActiveMQ and then running the service from service.msc got it working

Answer (score 3):

Take the \bin off of your JAVA_HOME

%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe

The script is adding it.

Try some of the troubleshooting here. Perhaps your version of the jdk is not compatible.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=238617797

Comment: i made a mistake when telling you my JAVA_HOME its actually C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27 and thats why ive added \bin\java.exe

Answer (score 1):

The same issue was solved by adding the location of JDK bin folder into PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

We can run a quick check to make sure we have everything required to run ActiveMQ by using command

> java -d64 -version

Answer (score 0):

Simply by adding the path var till /bin, solved the problem:

[image]